# Can I use a JSF validator both ways?

Tags: validation, jsf

I have an application where you can create Items. Those items are saved in a database with the primary key beeing its itemnumber. In the facelet where you create the Item I have a h:inputText with a validator which checks if the item is already in the database or not. If it is I give out an error message. I now have a second facelet where you can order Items by placing its number into an inputText field. Now I want the Validator to react in the opposite way as before.

So is there any way I can define the expected outcome of a validator? Or do I have to make a second validator?